# call.message = None в callback

Tags: python, telebot

Создаю бота с помощью `pytelegrambotapi`(`telebot`) и прорабатываю inline_handler. Мне нужно что бы с выводом кешированым аудио (`InlineQueryResultCachedAudio`) добавлялась кнопка с callback_data. Все хорошо, callback запрос проходит, но у меня нету call.message, то есть call.message = None. Что делать? Мне нужно получить id пользователя после нажатия кнопки. Вот мой код:

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def query_handler2(call):
    if call.data == '1':
        bot.send_message("Ваш id: "+str(call.message.chat.id)) # Тут ошибка. пишет что у NoneType объекта нету chat

@bot.inline_handler(lambda query: len(query.query) > 0)
def query_text(query):
    with sqlite3.connect("base.db") as con:
        c = con.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=? LIMIT 1", (query.from_user.id,))
        listr = []
        if c.fetchone() is None:
            pass
        else:
            c.execute("SELECT * FROM songs")
            l = 1
            def sing(name):
                listr.append(telebot.types.InlineQueryResultArticle(id=l, title='Исполнитель ' + name, input_message_content=telebot.types.InputTextMessageContent('Исполнитель ' + name, )))  #, input_message_content=telebot.types.InputTextMessageContent('Исполнитель ' + name, )
            for row in c:
                l+=1
                if query.query.lower() in str(row[0]).lower():
                    markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
                    markup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton("Мой id", callback_data="1"))
                    listr.append(telebot.types.InlineQueryResultCachedAudio(id=l, audio_file_id=row[3], caption="Песня "+row[0]+'\nИсполнитель '+row[2]+"\nЛайков: "+str(row[4]), reply_markup=markup))
                if query.query in row[2]:
                    sing(row[2])
                    break
            bot.answer_inline_query(query.id, listr)
```

Comment: А где ваш код? Добавьте его в вопрос

Comment: Я точно не помню уже, но попробуйте написать просто `print(call)` и посмотреть его содержимое. Возможно этот идентификатор есть по ключу в `from_user`, но могу ошибаться

Answer (score 1):

Я нашёл ответ. При `print(call)`, есть `from_user` в котором содержатся нужные данные, для получения (к примеру) `id` нужно использовать `call.from_user.id`.